# How to use the 3D Matrix for Rotation?

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d, rotation

I am using WPF 3D to show objects in Visual3D Port. Now I want to Rotate Model A towards Model B, depending on the Position on Model B in the XYZ Plane. I am trying to mimic what Unity does using its LookAt Function. I am not strong at math hence I am confused.

I have a 3D Matrix generated from the following function

```
public static Matrix3D CalculateLookAt(Vector3D eye, Vector3D at = new Vector3D(), Vector3D up = new Vector3D())
        {
            if (Math.Abs(up.Length - 0.0) < double.Epsilon) up = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
            var zaxis = (at - eye);
            zaxis.Normalize();
            var xaxis = Vector3D.CrossProduct(up, zaxis);
            xaxis.Normalize();
            var yaxis = Vector3D.CrossProduct(zaxis, xaxis);

            return new Matrix3D(
                xaxis.X, yaxis.X, zaxis.X, 0,
                xaxis.Y, yaxis.Y, zaxis.Y, 0,
                xaxis.Z, yaxis.Z, zaxis.Z, 0,
                Vector3D.DotProduct(xaxis, -eye), Vector3D.DotProduct(yaxis, -eye), Vector3D.DotProduct(zaxis, -eye), 1
            );
        }
```

Now how to use this Matrix?

Comment: vector * matrix ?

Comment: @Selvin but my matrix is 4x4 and vector is 1x3 or 3x1

Comment: huh? your matrix is Matrix3D ... your vector is Vector3D ... which ... has multiply operator with Matrix3D ... so where is the problem?

Comment: @Selvin but I get a vector 3d in result and how to use that in rotation?

Comment: the result is vector rotated(transformed) with matrix (if matrix transform is rotation)

Comment: How to use that in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.axisanglerotation3d?view=netcore-3.1](AxisAngleRotation3D)

Comment: the question was about matrix ... how to use ... prolly there is an example ... construct RotateTransform3D from it and use right method